# A couple of questions about SVD

Tags: linear-algebra, svd

As we know, the general linear mapping send the unit n-sphere into a n-ellipsoid.
 SVD decomposes this action into a sequence *1.rotation/reflection -- 2.shearing -- 3.rotation/reflection*.
The first question is: **why two rotoreflections**? As far I imagine, any action sending the unit spere into an ellipsoid should be decomposed as product of two transformations:
Simply shear the sphere, then rotate/reflect.
Second question has to do with the operator **A*A**. Every symmetric operator carries a bilinear n-form (that describes an n-surface). What this form has to do with SVD decomposition of A?

Thanks.

Comment: In my terminology the diagonal matrix performs a _scaling of the coordinate axes_ and not a shearing, but maybe I misunderstand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the SVD $$ A = U D V^*,$$

the "stretching" matrix $D$ is *diagonal* - this means that not only is it a stretching of the sphere into an ellipsoid, but it is one where the principal axes of the stretching are the cartesian coordinate axes. For a general stretching of the sphere into an ellipsoid these axes may not be aligned, which necessitates the rotation/reflection $V^*$.

In terms of linear transformations, it is entirely correct to look at it the way you suggest - by choosing the orthonormal basis made up by the columns of $V$, the transformation now has the matrix $$ V^* A V = (V^* U) D,$$ which is a stretching followed by a rotation/reflection as you describe.

Regarding the bilinear form corresponding to $A^*A$: it acts as$$(A^*A)(u,v) = u^* A^* A v = (Au)^*(Av) = \langle Au, Av \rangle;$$ so it is the pullback of the inner product on the codomain by the map $A$. Thus if $u$ is a singular vector (principal axis) with singular value (stretching factor) $\lambda$ we have $$(A^*A)(u,v) = \lambda^2 \langle u,v \rangle$$ for every $v$.

Comment: Very clear answer. Now, regarding second part, what do you mean by using the term "pullback of the inner product"? Pullback can have many meanings.
Furthermore, we know eigenvectors of A*A are the axes of the ellipsoid which is image of the unit sphere through A.
So x*A*Ax is precisely the quadratic form that describes this quadric surface, right?

Comment: @UzzoloDivendetta: by the pullback of $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ by $A$ I mean nothing more than $u,v \mapsto \langle Au, Av \rangle$. As for the surface, I don't think that's quite right - solutions to $1=x^*A^*Ax=|Ax|^2$ are those $x$ that map *to* the unit sphere.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right. Can we state any other geometrical consideration about A*A or AA* (also symmetric)?